# Pyhive Kerberos connection issue

Tags: hive, python-3.6, kerberos, pyhive

I'm getting following error while connecting to **hive** database configured with **Kerberos** using Python **pyhive** module.

```
kerberos_service_name should be set if and only if in KERBEROS mode
```

My Connection code:

```
import hive from pyhive

con = hive.Connection(host="hostnamexxxxx",port=10001,
                          database="db_namexxxx",username="usernamexxxx",
                          auth="KERBEROS",
                          kerberos_service_name="hive")
```

Full Error Trace:

```
 File "/xx/xx/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 126, in __init__
    raise ValueError("kerberos_service_name should be set if and only if in KERBEROS mode")
ValueError: kerberos_service_name should be set if and only if in KERBEROS mode
```

Also tried changing the **kerberos_service_name to 'attuid@principal'** but no luck.

could you please help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just was troubleshooting further the error was raised on line. if (kerberos_service_name is not None) != (auth == 'KERBEROS'):
            raise ValueError("kerberos_service_name should be set if and only if in KERBEROS mode"). so check the auth output and as I was getting the authentication value from config parser it was including the quotes in word 'KERBEROS' and hence was returning false when compared with string 'KERBEROS'

Comment: The issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just was troubleshooting further the error was raised on line.

`if (kerberos_service_name is not None) != (auth == 'KERBEROS'): raise ValueError("kerberos_service_name should be set if and only if in KERBEROS mode")`.

so check the **auth** output and as I was getting the authentication value from config parser it was including the quotes in word '**KERBEROS**' and hence was returning false when compared with string '**KERBEROS**'

i.e. 'KERBEROS' == ''KERBOROS''